# Object too big to see? Can you change the limitations?

Tags: modeling, rendering

I reached a satisfying goal on a certain project and decided to stretch the main objects to a realistic size (in metric). Finaly it was so big, that it disappeared when i set the camera in an appropriate position. I tried and it wasn´t visible in the render too. Is it possible to change the limitations?

[image]

The project is some kind of temple shaped like a giant head with the mouth as an entrance which would be at least 10 meters tall. This is how it looks before i size it up.

Comment: check camera clipping (3d view also has clipping settings, in the N panel)

Comment: Also check camera clipping in the properties window > camera data